# Trailing Sum Query

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

I am looking to summarize date and need to find a way of doing a 3 day trailing sum, sum of the current date and the 2 previous days.  I am using MariaDB, a MYSQL fork.

Here is a subset of the data;

```
select Date, Total from keywordSum limit 5;
+------------+--------+
| Date       | Total  |
+------------+--------+
| 2010-11-11 | 316815 |
| 2010-11-12 | 735305 |
| 2010-11-13 | 705116 |
| 2010-11-14 | 725020 |
| 2010-11-15 | 745378 |
+------------+--------+
```

I would like to end up with a result similar to this:

```
+------------+--------+-----------+
| Date       | Total  | 3DayTotal |
+------------+--------+-----------+
| 2010-11-11 | 316815 |    316815 |
| 2010-11-12 | 735305 |   1052120 |
| 2010-11-13 | 705116 |   1757236 |
| 2010-11-14 | 725020 |   2167441 |
| 2010-11-15 | 745378 |   2177514 |
+------------+--------+-----------+
```

It could even print NaN or leave it blank if the previous days don't exist. Any thoughts or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fast way using MySQL variables

Sample table:

```
create table keywordsum (date datetime, total int);
insert keywordsum values
('2010-11-11',316815),
('2010-11-12',735305),
('2010-11-13',705116),
('2010-11-14',725020),
('2010-11-15',745378);
```

Query:

```
select
  k.date, k.total, k.total + ifnull(@d1,0) + ifnull(@d2,0) running_total,
  @d2 := @d1,
  @d1 := k.total
from (select @d1 := null, @d2 := null) vars
cross join keywordsum k
order by k.date
```

(You can always subselect this to get only the first 3 columns)

Comment: Is there a better way of doing this when it involves many columns that I wish to do this to.

Comment: @Steven - multiple running totals? yes, with a pair of variables per running total

Comment: Also this does have a flaw in that if not every day has a record in the dataset, it won't act correctly. It will sum the current line with the previous 2 lines, not necessarily the previous 2 days.

Comment: Is it possible to have a day appear twice? Which record would you take as the contribution "for that day? I would use this type of query with a LEFT JOIN from a calendar table, to preserve the O(n) performance

Answer (score 3):

One simple way is to join the table to itself.  Make sure it is indexed on a combination of date and total.

```
select t1.date
     , t1.total
     , t1.total 
      +coalesce(t2.total,0)
      +coalesce(t3.total,0)
  from theTable t1
  left 
  join theTable t2 on t1.date = date_Add(t2.date,interval 1 day)
  left
  join theTable t3 on t1.date = date_Add(t3.date,interval 2 day)
```

Comment: Your answer got me on the right track. What i did instead of joining with other tables, was execute a subquery. Here it is "select t1.Date, t1.Total, (Select sum(Total) from keywordSum where Date<=t1.Date and Date>=Date(t1.Date-2)) as 3DayTotal from keywordSum t1 limit 5;"

Comment: @steven glad to hear it got you on track.  Subqueries work too.  I'm not sure though you need that "LIMIT 5".

Comment: @Steven This answer will perform badly when your table is large. The triple join will make for O(N^3) performance, that is to say, for 1000 records, it will be about 1 million times slower than for 10 records. See my answer