# MySQL Moving 12 Month Sum by Group

Tags: mysql, group-by, sum, moving-average

I want to get the sum of values over the previous 12 months, similar to:

[Trailing Sum Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5160120/trailing-sum-query)

The main difference is that I want the trailing 12 month sum, where each group is calculated independently.  Here's sample data where the quarters are always continuous.

```
create table keywordsum (date1 datetime, val int, group1 int);
insert keywordsum values
('2011-03-31',10,1),
('2011-06-30',20,1),
('2011-09-30',30,1),
('2011-12-31',40,1),
('2012-03-31',50,1),
('2012-06-30',60,1),
('2010-12-31',1,2),
('2011-03-31',2,2),
('2011-06-30',3,2),
('2011-09-30',4,2),
('2011-12-31',5,2),
('2012-03-31',6,2);
```

Here's the desired output:

```
date1,moving_sum,group1
('2011-03-31',NULL,1),
('2011-06-30',NULL,1),
('2011-09-30',NULL,1),
('2011-12-31',100,1),
('2012-03-31',140,1),
('2012-06-30',180,1),
('2010-12-31',NULL,2),
('2011-03-31',NULL,2),
('2011-06-30',NULL,2),
('2011-09-30',10,2),
('2011-12-31',14,2),
('2012-03-31',18,2);
```

For example, trailing_sum for row 6, or group=1 and 2012-06-30 is the sum of rows 3-6, or the group=1 values for 2011-09-30, 2011-12-31, 2012-03-31 and 2012-06-30 = 30+40+50+60=180.  Trailing sum for row 3, or group=1 and 2011-09-30 is NULL because there aren't four values preceding 2011-09-30.  Similarly, trailing sum for 2nd to last row, group=2 and 2011-12-31 is the sum of group=2 values 2011-03-31 to 2011-12-31 = 2+3+4+5 = 14.  trailing_sum for row 8, group=2 and 2011-03-31 is NULL because there aren't four values between 2010-06-30 to 2011-03-31 in group=2.

When I try GROUP BY, I always end up with one row for each group.  How do I get the desired output?  Thanks.

Comment: But it's always going to be near march, right? And there are always 3 rows per 'group'?

Comment: I don't understand the relationship between the desired output and the input data.  Can you better describe what you want?

Comment: Strawberry - I edited the question, so the edits may answer your question.  Gordon - the description following the output describes the relationship.  I also fixed dates in the input and output that should clarify the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I get it.

The following gets the moving sum, but not `NULL` for the first three values:

```
select date1,
       (select sum(val)
        from keywordsum kws2
        where kws2.date1 between kws.date - interval 365+15 day and kws.date and
              kws2.group1 = kws.group1
       ) as moving_sum,
       group1
from keywordsum kws;
```

For that, use a `case` statement:

```
select date1,
       (select (case when count(*) = 4 then sum(val) end)
        from keywordsum kws2
        where kws2.date1 between kws.date - interval 365+15 day and kws.date and
              kws2.group1 = kws.group1
       ) as moving_sum,
       group1
from keywordsum kws;
```

Comment: Your answer is easily understandable to a novice like myself.

Comment: If anyone else uses this, the answer is correct, but do a quick check on a subset of data.  it's O(n^2), which made it impractical for my case with millions of rows.